# oauth2client crash when reading Google-provided JSON keyfile

Tags: python, unicode, oauth-2.0

Using a Google API JSON keyfile downloaded from the Google Console, and using `google-api-python-client==1.5.5` and `oauth2client==4.0.0`, and using python 3.5 on my local Mac, this works fine:

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
  settings.GOOGLE_KEY_FILE_PATH, scopes).create_delegated(
  settings.GOOGLE_SUB_USER)
```

and I can proceed to query APIs. But on a production Ubuntu server (which is on Python 3.4), with the same exact code and keyfile, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.../python3.4/site-packages/oauth2client/service_account.py", line 220, in from_json_keyfile_name
    client_credentials = json.load(file_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 265, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/.../python3.4/codecs.py", line 319, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

The dependencies are the same, the code is the same, the keyfile is the same. Is there some difference between Python 3.4 and 3.5 that could account for this? Or is there something I can do to re-encode the keyfile that will make Python 3.4 happy with it? Or is something else going on?

Comment: I've returned to using the .p12 keyfile provided by Google rather than the JSON to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when my application name included Unicode.